# Load about:blank page with content in URL

Tags: html, browser, html4, frontpage

Back in the day, I used to be able to open a web browser (worked on Internet Explorer 7 for sure) and type in something with `about:` in the browser's address bar, along with some simple text like "Hello, World!".

The page would then change to `about:blank` in the address bar, and my text "Hello, World" would show up on the page.  I remember basic HTML worked in general as well.

Problem:  I forgot the syntax for doing this in the browser's address bar.  Is this still supported?

I seen another post that does something similar with javascript, but the method I want to use had `about:` somewhere at the beginning of the address bar.  I first discovered this technique when I was using Microsoft FrontPage by accident.

As well, I recently came across a QR code that did the same thing, about:blank page was in the address bar, and the page content was just text.

Essentially, I want to create a link/URL that loads a text message without pointing to a file or actual webpage.

---

For example, I want this result:`data:,Hello%2C%20World!` 
but need the address bar to show about:blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode any kind of data via the [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

> ```
>  data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
> ```

For example: `data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxk`